# displaying fractions in gtk

Tags: user-interface, math, gtk, pango

Is it possible to display fractions in a gtk widget like GtkTextView, presumably via using pango markup? I'm looking for something which is possible to edit by a user, so e.g. a pixbuf with a rendered png file is not ok.

Also I need arbitrarily long enumerators and denominators so

```
<sup>a</sup>/<sub>b</sub>
```

is not acceptable.

Comment: You mean like GtkMathView?

Comment: Isn't gtkmathview a rendering engine? If it is then it's not what I want, as I want to be able to display fractions in an editable way. Also, I haven't said it but I'm doing it in python and I coudn't google anything about using gtkmathview in python

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. I don't know what your use case is, but to make an editable horizontal fraction (as in `$\frac{a}{b}$`) I would suggest doing something like putting two `GtkEntry` widgets without borders into a grid, and draw a line between them (or use a `GtkSeparator`.) You could even embed this grid inside a `GtkTextView` if you needed it to be inline.